# Oracle SQL - Get aggregate data

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-apex

I have two tables, one with the products, and other with relation product/model and I want to get all the related table in the form:

```
{
"product":"bown",
"models":["a","b"]
}
```

How I can do this? I tried SELECTED, INNER JOIN, but the max that I could see is like some:

```
{
"product":"bown",
"models":"a"
},
{
"product":"bown",
"models":"b
}.
```

And this is inefficient.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '{"product":"' || product_name || '", "models":["' || LISTAGG(model_name, '","') || '"]}' JSON_data
FROM product
JOIN product_model USING (product_id)
JOIN model USING (model_id)
GROUP BY product_name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5b47ff8d6691e94121c29081634f615)